Hermiticity of Majorana Fermions: SYK Model
The SYK Hamiltonian is defined as
$$H = -\frac{1}{4!}\sum_{i,j,k,l=0}^{L-1} J_{ijkl} c^x_{i}c^x_{j}c^x_{k}c^x_{l},$$
where $J_{ijkl}$ is a random all-to-all interaction strength which is normally distributed with zero mean and unit variance, and $c^x_j$ is a Majorana fermion satisfying $c^x_j = (c^x_j)^\dagger,\ (c^x_j)^2 = 1,$ and $\{c^x_i,c^x_j\} = 0$ for $i\not = j$.
Numerically, this Hamiltonian can be constructed using a Python library QuSpin, as described in this example. A problem that I'm facing is that the constructed Hamiltonian doesn't obey $H = H^\dagger$, although the library suggests that it passes the hermiticity test. I want to ask if there's a different definition of the hermiticity condition that the above Hamiltonian obeys.
Note: I am not very sure where this question should be asked, but perhaps people in PSE might have encountered this.

What makes you say $H \neq H^{\dagger}$?

I meant numerically. Numerical, if you check the hermiticity of the Hamiltonian constructed from QuSpin, it is not hermitian though, it's function check_herm says, it is.

How are you checking if $H=H^\dagger$? It may be the case that floating point errors mean $H-H^\dag\neq=0$ but is simply very very small (around machine epsilon)

I am sure that the error is not coming from their, since apparent from just looking at the matrix that it's not hermitian. It has a structure such that $a_{ij} = -a_{ji}$.

Well, you should be able to show quite readily that $H^{\dagger} = H$ analytically; hint: given four Majorana operators $c_j$, $j = 1,2,3,4$, what is $(c_1 c_2 c_3 c_4)^{\dagger}$? So, the only possibility is a bug in your code. If you're finding instead that $H$ is anti-Hermitian, then there may be a factor of $i$ missing somewhere.

@Zack It is not exactly anti-Hermitian, since the diagonals are real.
